# AWS: Can't get headers to update in Lambda@Edge function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda-edge

I created a static website from a CloudFormation template. It added a Lambda@Edge function which adds response headers. I need to update the Content Security Policy header to include some external resources (script, fonts), SVG images, etc.

I made the changes, deployed the lambda, added an invalidation to CloudFront to clear cache, but the headers are still not updated. I've done this multiple times with the same result. it simply does not update when I browse the site. What am I missing??

Here's the Lambda code:

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    //Get contents of response
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;
    
    // Content Security 
    const csp = "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self' www.google.com ; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; object-src 'none'";

//Set new headers 
 headers['strict-transport-security'] = [{key: 'Strict-Transport-Security', value: 'max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload'}]; 
 headers['content-security-policy'] = [{key: 'Content-Security-Policy', value: csp}]; 
 headers['x-content-type-options'] = [{key: 'X-Content-Type-Options', value: 'nosniff'}]; 
 headers['x-frame-options'] = [{key: 'X-Frame-Options', value: 'DENY'}]; 
 headers['x-xss-protection'] = [{key: 'X-XSS-Protection', value: '1; mode=block'}]; 
 headers['referrer-policy'] = [{key: 'Referrer-Policy', value: 'same-origin'}]; 
    
    //Return modified response
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

After much hair-pulling, I ended up removing the 'content-security-policy' header completely just to get the site working again (see the code above in my original question). I'm going to spin up another CloudFormation stack to see if I can get the CSP working properly. When I get this figured out, I will post more info here.